# C++, разрешен ли повторный вызов деструктора?

Tags: c++, деструктор

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что говорит `Стандарт C++` про повторный вызов деструктора?

Можно ли вызывать деструктор объекта несколько раз при условии, что объект остается в корректном состоянии?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нельзя, согласно:

> Standard 12.4/14
>
> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer
>   exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an
>   object whose lifetime has ended (3.8).

Теперь ответ на:

> Можно ли вызывать деструктор объекта несколько раз при условии, что
>   объект остается в корректном состоянии?

Это тоже нет - так как это уже не существующий с точки зрения стандарта объект, то повторный вызов деструктора приводит к неопределённому поведению в не зависимости от валидности (или корректности) состояния объекта

Answer (score 3):

Повторный вызов деструктора, как и любого другого метода объекта после вызова деструктора является неопределнным поведеним, так как жизнь объекта оканчивается при начале вызова деструктора согласно

> **6.6.3 Object lifetime [basic.life]**
>   The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:
>   — (1.3) if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (15.4), the destructor call starts, or
>   — (1.4) the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o (6.6.2).

и

> **15.4 Destructors [class.dtor]**
>   16 Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended (6.6.3).